# Is using an "object" property a proper thing to do?

Tags: c#, object, casting, properties

I have to get back an object the frontend is sending me. Thing is, front team wanted their component to be as generic as it can be so, in the dto, i'll recieve a `Value` property that can be different things (a boolean, a string, a list a strings, a numeric value...), as following :

```
"conditions": [
        {
          "alias": "FSTNM",
          "providerKey": "Marketing",
          "hasValue": true,
          "conditionType": "Text",
          "values": "john",
          "startDate": null,
          "endDate": null
        },
        {
          "alias": "LSTNM",
          "providerKey": "Marketing",
          "hasValue": true,
          "conditionType": "Text",
          "values": null,
          "startDate": null,
          "endDate": null
        },
        {
          "alias": "BTHDT",
          "providerKey": "Marketing",
          "hasValue": true,
          "conditionType": "DateTime",
          "values": null,
          "startDate": "02-10-1980",
          "endDate": "17-08-1989"
        },
        {
          "alias": "AMECH",
          "providerKey": "Custom",
          "hasValue": true,
          "conditionType": "Boolean",
          "values": true,
          "startDate": null,
          "endDate": null
        },
        {
          "alias": "CMBCH",
          "providerKey": "Custom",
          "hasValue": true,
          "conditionType": "Number",
          "values": 2,
          "startDate": null,
          "endDate": null
        },
         {
          "alias": "FVRDR",
          "providerKey": "Custom",
          "hasValue": true,
          "conditionType": "List",
          "values": [
            1,
            3
          ],
          "startDate": null,
          "endDate": null
        }

      ]
```

So, I tried to set the `Values` property as `object` like this :

```
 public class DataTableFilterValueDTO
    {            
        public string Alias { get; set; }
        public string ProviderKey { get; set; }
        public bool HasValue { get; set; }
        public string ConditionType { get; set; }
        public object Values { get; set; }
        public string StartDate { get; set; }
        public string EndDate { get; set; }       
    }
```

It seems that it works. When the request reack my controller, `Values` seems to be the right type, and depending on `conditionType`, I can cast it to the object i'm supposed to retrieve, like this :

## If conditionType  = "Text" :

```
var values = condition.Values as string;
```

## If conditionType  = "Boolean" :

```
var values = condition.Values as bool;
```

## If conditionType  = "List" :

```
var values = condition.Values as List<string>;
```

But is this a  thing to do?
I mean, it does not feel right using this but I've never worked with the `object`type and can't really tell when it's good to use it.

Comment: You almost never want to use the object type directly.

Comment: "to be as generic as it can be" - then why not use generics?

Comment: .... because then you'll need to know the type at compile time or, worse, use reflection to create it. A whole other set of problems @CodeStranger

Comment: @Jamiec Well, knowing the type at compile-time isn´t neccessarily hard. Maybe OP knows the possible types beforehand. Anyway I agree Broots, the term "generic" often tends to imply `dynamic` or `object`, of which both are often not needed and make developing harder than it has to be. Actually we usually don´t want "every possible type", but a certain "set of types", which implies generics. However there´s indeed not much common between string, bool and List.

Comment: Thanks for all you answers ! So, if I understand it well, that's not very good to use object. But what would be my other choices? Because as @HimBromBeere sais : `there´s indeed not much common between string, bool and List `

Comment: Your main other choice is to get the front end team to stop arbitrarily imposing their JavaScript-style loose typing on you and have them send the values in dedicated fields. Then you can deserialize them directly into your strongly-typed equivalents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a Custom `JsonConverter`. To do this, declare your class as abstract, and define a class that inherits it for each data type you expect to receive, like so:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(ValueConverter))]
public abstract class Value
{
    public string Alias { get; set; }
    public string ProviderKey { get; set; }
    public bool HasValue { get; set; }
    public string ConditionType { get; set; }
    public string StartDate { get; set; }
    public string EndDate { get; set; }
}

public class BooleanValue : Value { public bool? Values { get; set; } }

public class ListValue : Value { public List<string> Values { get; set; } }

public class StringValue : Value { public string Values { get; set; } }

public class DateTimeValue : Value { public DateTime? Values { get; set; } }

public class IntegerValue : Value { public int? Values { get; set; } }
```

Then you need to define your custom `JsonConverter` where you perform the type conversion according to the value of the `conditionType` property:

```
public class ValueConverter : JsonConverter
{
    static readonly JsonSerializerSettings SpecifiedSubclassConversion  = new JsonSerializerSettings() { ContractResolver = new CustomResolver() };

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => objectType == typeof(Value);

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);
        return (obj["conditionType"].Value<string>()) switch
        {
            "Text" => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StringValue>(obj.ToString(), SpecifiedSubclassConversion),
            "DateTime" => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTimeValue>(obj.ToString(), SpecifiedSubclassConversion),
            "Boolean" => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BooleanValue>(obj.ToString(), SpecifiedSubclassConversion),
            "Number" => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IntegerValue>(obj.ToString(), SpecifiedSubclassConversion),
            "List" => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ListValue>(obj.ToString(), SpecifiedSubclassConversion),
            _ => throw new Exception("Unknown conditionType"),
        };
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class CustomResolver: DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonConverter ResolveContractConverter(Type objectType)
    {
        if (typeof(Value).IsAssignableFrom(objectType) && !objectType.IsAbstract)
            return null;

        return base.ResolveContractConverter(objectType);
    }
}
```

And finally the usage:

```
foreach (var value in JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Value>>(json))
{
    if (value is StringValue)
    {
        string s = ((StringValue)value).Values;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that detailed answer. I'll give it a try ! Question is, I don't know that syntax, is that c# 7? Or is it higher?

Comment: @j0w my bad, the switch statement syntactic sugar might require C# 7 and above, but you can rewrite it as a regular switch. The rest of the code shouldn't give you any troubles version-wise.

Comment: yeah figured out it's c#8 syntax so rewried the switch statment and it works just fiine ! Thanks a lot :)